# Optimizing computational-complexity of linear-algebraic operations

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, computational-complexity, machine-learning

> This question is from Stanford CS221 Autumn 2019-2020, [Foundations](https://stanford-cs221.github.io/autumn2019/assignments/foundations/index.html), Problem 2.d

Consider the scalar-valued function $f(w)$ defined as follows:

$$
f(\mathbf{w})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\mathbf{a}_{i}^\intercal \mathbf{w}−\mathbf{b}_{j}^\intercal \mathbf{w})^2+\lambda \lVert \mathbf{w} \rVert_2^2
$$

where, $\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ (represented as a column vector) and constants $\mathbf{a}_i,\mathbf{b}_j \in \mathbb{R}^d$ (also represented as column vectors) and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$,

Devise a strategy that first does preprocessing in $O(nd^2)$ time, and then for any given vector $\mathbf{w}$, takes $O(d^2)$ time instead to compute $f(w)$.
[**Hint**: Refactor the algebraic expression; this is a classic trick used in machine learning. Again, you may find it helpful to work out the scalar case first.]

**My Solution**: I do not know what the "classic trick" is! But, I did the following:

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\mathbf{a}_{i}^\intercal \mathbf{w}−\mathbf{b}_{j}^\intercal \mathbf{w})^2 & = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\biggl[(\mathbf{a}_{i}^\intercal \mathbf{w})^2 + (\mathbf{b}_{j}^\intercal \mathbf{w})^2 - 2 (\mathbf{a}_{i}^\intercal \mathbf{w})(\mathbf{b}_{j}^\intercal \mathbf{w})\biggr] \\
& =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\mathbf{a}_{i}^\intercal \mathbf{w})^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\mathbf{b}_{j}^\intercal \mathbf{w})^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\mathbf{a}_{i}^\intercal \mathbf{w})(\mathbf{b}_{j}^\intercal \mathbf{w})\\
&=n\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\mathbf{a}_{i}^\intercal \mathbf{w})^2 + n\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\mathbf{b}_{j}^\intercal \mathbf{w})^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\mathbf{a}_{i}^\intercal \mathbf{w})\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\mathbf{b}_{j}^\intercal \mathbf{w}) & \text{eq.1}\\
\end{align*}
$$

In the above, eq.1, we have:

- Computing $\mathbf{a}_{i}^\intercal \mathbf{w}$ takes time $O(d)$ for each $i=1,2,
  \dots,n$; therefore, computing the first-term takes time $O(nd)$
- Computing $\mathbf{b}_{j}^\intercal \mathbf{w}$ takes time $O(d)$ for each $j=1,2,\dots,n$; therefore, computing the second-term takes time $O(nd)$
- Similarly, from the above two points we can conclude that the third-term, also takes time $O(nd)$ - computing each summation individually and then taking the product of their results.
- Expressing $\lVert \mathbf{w} \rVert_2^2$ as $\mathbf{w}^\intercal\mathbf{w}$, we can compute the L2-norm in time $O(d)$.

So, the total running time is $O(nd)$! (**Am I missing something? and Also, how to solve the above problem?**)

Comment: But $O(nd)$ is what you have to pay for every new vector $\mathbf{w}$ with your solution: if you want to evaluate $f$ on $m \gg n$ inputs, then your cost scales as $m n d$ instead of the $md^2$ asked. (I am assuming here $d \ll n$.)

Comment: @ClementC. - what does $m$ here refer to? (there is no $m$ in the question)

Comment: Hint: the solution is of the form $f(w) = w^T M w$ where $M$ is a single $d \times d$ matrix that you precompute out of $a_{i}$, $b_{j}$ and $\lambda$

Comment: The number of points you want to evaluate $f$ on (I gave it the name $m$, it's not in the question). The whole idea of doing preprocessing to speed up later computations is only useful if you want to perform many of those computations, to "amortize" the preprocessing time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution, $O(nd)$ is what you have to pay for *every* new vector $\mathbf{w}$ with your solution: if you want to evaluate $f$ on $m \gg n$ inputs, then your cost scales as $m n d$ instead of the $md^2$ asked. *(I am assuming here $d \ll n$, otherwise your solution is indeed faster)*.

To obtain what is expected, rewrite
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\mathbf{a}_{i}^\intercal \mathbf{w}−\mathbf{b}_{j}^\intercal \mathbf{w})^2
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^d\sum_{\ell=1}^d(\mathbf{a}_{i,k}−\mathbf{b}_{j,k})\mathbf{w}_k(\mathbf{a}_{i,\ell}−\mathbf{b}_{j,\ell})\mathbf{w}_\ell \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^d\sum_{\ell=1}^d \underbrace{\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\mathbf{a}_{i,k}−\mathbf{b}_{j,k})(\mathbf{a}_{i,\ell}−\mathbf{b}_{j,\ell}) \right)}_{\gamma_{k,\ell}}\mathbf{w}_k\mathbf{w}_\ell
\end{align*}$$
Now, using the same idea as you have, show that you can compute each $\gamma_{k,\ell}$ (which do not depend on $\mathbf{w}$!) ahead of time in time $O(n)$. Thus, computing all of them takes preprocessing time $O(nd^2)$.

Once you have that, given a new $\mathbf{w}$ you only have to compute
$$
f(\mathbf{w}) = \sum_{k=1}^d\sum_{\ell=1}^d  \gamma_{k,\ell} \mathbf{w}_k\mathbf{w}_\ell + \lambda\sum_{k=1}^d \mathbf{w}_k^2
$$
which takes time $O(d^2+d)=O(d^2)$.